# Centering contentplaceholders

Tags: .net, css, master-pages

I have a contentplaceholder which needs to be centered (as close to absolute as possible)
to the center of the page. The issue I am having is when, the browser moves to different resolutions the centering is thrown off.

I have tried using divs and tables. I have switched out the precent with em units, and still no workie. Any help would be greatly appreciated. My end goal is to have the contentplaceholder always be in the center of page regardless of the resolution of the monitor

```
    <div style="width:20%"/>
<div style="width:60">
contentplaceholercode
</div>
<div style="width:20%"/>


<table>
<tr >
<td style="width:20%">
</td>
<td style="width:60>
</td>
<td style="width:20%">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

code for master and code for content page

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Master.master.cs" Inherits="WorkRecordr.Master" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

    <script src="Assets/Scripts/Jqeury1.4.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
            background-color: #326598;
        }
        .outer
        {
            width: 100%;
            border: solid 1px gray;
            padding: 1px;
        }
        .inner
        {
            border: solid 1px gray;
            width: 70%;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="text-align: center">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
          <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>





<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="WorkRecordr.test" MasterPageFile="~/Master.Master" %>


<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
aaaaaaaaa***aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa***aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        .outer{
            width:100%;
            border:solid 1px gray;
            padding:1px;

        }
        .inner{
            border:solid 1px gray;
            width:60%;
            margin-left:auto;
            margin-right:auto;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="outer">
            <div class="inner">content</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not quit there. IT still resizes when I change monitor resultions. I have two monitors one at 1440X900 and the other at 1920 X1080. Going to the second monitor messes up the align. I have pasted the code into my original question.

Comment: I mean, when my monitor resolution changes the physical positioning of the elements also changes. The content in the contentplaceholder aligns differenlty

Comment: I guess I can just live with it. Thank you for trying

Comment: Try giving .inner a fixed width rather than 60%.

Comment: But wouldn't that just force the page to only be centered on 1 resolution. I want it to be completely relative, and at any resolution become centered.